Unable to Identify any element present in Mobile App developed in Flutter
Platform : Android
Appium version : 2.4.1
Real Device: Galaxy Tab A7 Lite
Language: Java & Appium
Your OS : Windows 10
Hi: I'm trying to automate Mobile app developed in Flutter. I requested Developer to add Semantics label in Flutter development code, so that the app is displaying in Appium Inspector with resource Id or Id. But, Even appium inspector identifies as Id, that Id could not enter any values to that control in app. like SendKeys methods are doing nothing.
Appium Inspector
Sample code
`Thread.sleep(3000);
rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");//Read config.properties.
AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
service.start();
sAssertinFn = new SoftAssert();
UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
options.setDeviceName("R9ZR908HTNR");
options.setPlatformVersion("14.0");
options.setPlatformName("Android");

//  options.setAutomationName("UiAutomator2");
options.setAutomationName("Flutter");
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\" + "app-profile.apk");
options.setCapability("app", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\" + "app-profile.apk");
options.setCapability("appium:noReset", false);
options.setCapability("appium:fullReset", true);

options.setCapability("appPackage","com.example.automation");
options.setCapability("appActivity","com.example.automation.MainActivity");
options.setCapability("autoDismissAlerts", true);
options.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
options.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);`

I tried installing appium flutter driver, and asked developer to give unique Id for each widget/flutter control. And configured appium default service, invoked app compiled in debug or profile mode. Used the locator identified in appium inspector to send value to the element through appium java code. But, no activity happeneds on those controls.
